# How to manage user Onboarding Screen in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

How to Check when press the app icon that user is newly user for that app. and if that user is newly show onboard screen for this this user.

Comment: did you find any soluation for this ?

Comment: not yet.. do you know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the initialization of the app you can do a check if the user has finished the onboarding. You can do the check by using the local storage / Ionic storage. I would suggest to do the check in `app.component.ts`.

Example:

app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    ...
    private router: Router,
    private storageService: StorageService,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      
      // Method to send user to onboarding pages
      this.pushToAppOnboarding();
    });
  }


  async pushToAppOnboarding() {
   await this.storageService.getItem('onboarding').then((key) => {
      // StorageService only takes strings. Thus, compare if the string equals 'true'.
      if (key.value !== 'true') { 
        this.router.navigate(['/onboarding']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

onboarding.page.html

```html
<ion-content>
  <!-- place your onboarding content here. Use e.g. ion-slider -->
  <ion-button (click)="finishAppOnboarding()">Lets Start</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

onboarding.page.ts

```js
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private storageService: StorageService,
  ) { } 

  finishAppOnboarding() {
    this.storageService.setItem('onboarding', 'true');
    this.router.navigate(['/route-to-your-homepage']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use localstorage to check if the app is opened for the first time and display an onboarding modal or page accordingly :

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

this.storage.get('firstOpening').then((firstOpening) => {
    if (!firstOpening) {
      //Open onboarding modal or navigate to page
    }
  });
```

And before leaving your onboarding page your can set the value in localstorage, so the page will not be displayed again :

```
this.storage.set("firstOpening", true);
```